# VS2010 / MSSQL - References to another database server's master

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a VS 2010 solution that contains two database projects, `FirstDatabase` and `SecondDatabase`. Each has a database reference to `master` and `msdb`, and `FirstDatabase` has a reference to `SecondDatabase`.

In the execution environment, the two databases are on separate servers. Therefore, in VS2010, `FirstDatabase`'s reference to `SecondDatabase` is defined with a server variable name `$(OtherServer)`.

`FirstDatabase` contains a function `executeIfUp()` that tests whether `SecondDatabase` on `OtherServer` is up:

```
create function executeIfUp() returns int as 
begin
 declare @value int
 set @value = 0
 if (select [state] from [$(OtherServer)].master.sys.databases where [name] = 'SecondDatabase') = 0
 begin /* do stuff */ end
 return @value
end
```

The problem is that VS2010 complains of a missing reference:

`SQL04151: Function: [dbo].[executeIfUp] has an unresolved reference to object [$(OtherServer)].[master].[sys].[databases].[name].`

This is apparently happening because VS2010 does not interpret `[$(OtherServer)].master` to be a reference to the `master` database (which nominally has the same schema on all MSSQL servers). If I add an additional database reference to `[$(OtherServer)].master` to `FirstDatabase`'s database project, I get an error saying that there are duplicate references to `master` in `FirstDatabase`'s database project.

My question is: how do I get VS2010 to resolve `[$(OtherServer)].master` as a valid reference?

Comment: What does mean `server variable name $(OtherServer)`? Are you mean msbuild property?

Comment: Hi @HamletHakobyan, server variable `$(OtherServer)` refers to VS2010's use of SQLCMD variables to stand in for server and database names. See [the MSDN documentation on this topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386242(v=vs.100).aspx#Cross-DatabaseReference) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

From the documentation you referenced "If you refer to an object in a database project on another server, you must define it as a linked server on your target server" (see http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff772782.aspx).  Also make sure that $(OtherServer) is setup as a **Server** Variable.

1. Click Define server variable.
2. In Name, type a name for the variable that represents the server.
3. In Value, type the name of the server that the variable represents.

Comment: Hi @BateTech, thanks for your response. The link you attached describes how to create a linked server on a database server using SQL Management Studio (which one would do after deploying the database to the server). We have already done this and `executeIfUp()` works correctly in production. The problem I describe in my question is happening in Visual Studio at design time.

Comment: What if you create a synonym in SQL Server for the master database on the other server, using the linked server. Master. Databases for the synonym? And then in your VS project you don't have to use the server variable. We have used synonyms like this for cross database refs on a test server in cases where we have multiple non-prod instances on the same server, but haven't tried with separate servers before but in theory should work.

Comment: Actually I just read that you cannot create a synonym for a reference to a linked server.  But now I'm asking myself.... why not just name the linked server the same thing in test and production? That way you don't need the server variable in your VS project.  We do this for Oracle linked server references for our non-prod instances.  We have a linked server named something like OracleEBS, and just switch out the data source that it points too for the non-prods while keeping the linked server name the same.

Comment: Hi @BateTech - We do have the same linked server name in our test and production environments. I don't think Visual Studio has a concept of Linked Servers at design / compile time - instead, it requires the use of server name variables to be able to validate the schema at compile time, which is what we're trying to do.

Answer (score -1):

In Visual Studio 2012 (I don't know if it works for 2010) you can right click the database project, add a database reference, select system database and select 'master'.